# Cannot assign names when converting matrix using as.data.frame

Tags: r

I want to generate a two-column data frame that has a given correlation. Two columns named "x" and "y". There are tons of ways to do this, sampling from a multivariate normal distribution being one. So, for 50 rows of correlation `r = 0.95`, this works:

```r
myFrame <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.56,0.56,1),, ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE))
myFrame
```

...but you'll notice that the column names are V1 and V2. I've read what I think is relevant in the docs, but I can't get the names to change.

I've tried using `col.names = c("x", "y")` in various places. It seems it would go between the final two closed parentheses, but I've tried other places. Even though I didn't think it correct, I tried `names = c("x, y")` as well, to no avail.

I understand I could use a second step to change the names, but since `as.data.frame()` accepts a vector to name the columns, I shouldn't have to resort to that.

Comment: From a quick look, `as.data.frame.matrix` doesn't have a `col.names=` argument passed through. It works on a `list` however - `as.data.frame(list(1:2,2:3), col.names=c("one","two"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, neither `data.frame()` nor the `matrix` method for `as.data.frame` have an argument to let you set column names.

The standard way, as you say, would be to set the names of the object in a second line of code. If that is abhorrent to you, you can still get it done in a single line. Here are two options:

```
myFrame1 = as.data.frame("colnames<-"(mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.56, 0.56, 1), ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE), c("x", "y")))

myFrame2 = setNames(as.data.frame(mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.56, 0.56, 1), ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE)), c("x", "y"))

# I would prefer using two lines, much clearer:
myFrame3 = as.data.frame(mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.56, 0.56, 1), ncol = 2), empirical = TRUE))
names(myFrame3) = c("x", "y")

# Or, if you're a fine of pipes:
library(magrittr)
myFrame4 = mvrnorm(
    10, 
    mu = c(0,0),
    Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.56, 0.56, 1), ncol = 2),
     empirical = TRUE
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(c("x", "y"))
```

---

When looking at `?as.data.frame`, these are the methods described:

```
## S3 method for class 'character'
as.data.frame(x, ...,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

## S3 method for class 'list'
as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...,
              cut.names = FALSE, col.names = names(x), fix.empty.names = TRUE,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

## S3 method for class 'matrix'
as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE,
              make.names = TRUE, ...,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

Notice that the `matrix` method *does not* have a `col.names` argument. Only the `list` method does. So in converting a `list` to a `data.frame`, you can use `col.names`, but not converting a `matrix`.